# How to know how much recent activity has been seen by a person having access to my Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, browser-history

My estranged wife has possession of my phone. I locked her out of Gmail access as soon as possible. Despite my efforts I can't view from my PC in my security settings how much recent activity she saw on my Gmail and what she was browsing while on my device. I'm afraid that my opportunity to obtain this info has passed because I didn't check the history before I signed out of all devices. Is there still hope ?

Answer (score 0):

If you used Chrome for Android as your phone's web browser, you should be able to view its history by opening Chrome on your desktop, going to History, and selecting "Other Devices" (also requires you are signed into Chrome on your PC, and, I believe, a sync setting enabled in PC Chrome).

For other apps, though, most do not retain any such logs, let alone provide a mechanism for remotely accessing them.

(Keeping an activity history on the device itself would be impractical due to the limited write lifecycle of the internal storage; Chrome retains your browsing history in the cloud as a convenience.)

Comment: Google secures this data (any cloud provider should) in such a way as to not be readily accessible to their employees or hackers. However, many people are hyper-reactive regarding internet privacy, and erroneously assume anything in the cloud is accessible to the cloud provider, so they disable such features and advise others to do the same. My local news recently instructed viewers to disable Location History, without explaining that doing so breaks some very useful features, like telling you about heavy traffic on your daily commute, or when to leave to get to your appointment on time.)